# Problem with 7-segment display: dimly lit when off

Tags: arduino, shift-register, 7segmentdisplay

I'm driving two large seven-segment displays using two shift registers (74HC595). The displays have a forward voltage of 12V and a max forward current of 20mA.

I'm feeding data and 5V of power to the shift registers from the my Arduino and I used used an external 12V supply for the displays, but I was planning to use a larger (18V) supply later. I hooked 12V + to the common anodes of the two displays, then connected the segments to the proper pins on the shift registers. I put a 330 ohm resistor between the SR pins and the segment cathodes. My plan was to use 18V, so I figured that 330 would limit my current to 18mA per segment. When running with the 12V supply, I expected the segments would be dimmer, but work fine.

So, all of my prototyping with 12V worked fine. When I switched over to using 18V (from two 9V batteries wired in series) I noticed that one of the displays seems to be dimly lit even when all of the segments are supposed to be off. (They still light up as they should when on.)

FWIW, it appears to only happen to the display that's connected to the first shift register - i.e., the first one in the chain that receives data directly from the Arduino. The other display (driven by the second SR) seems fine.

I'm a bit of a newb, so I would not be surprised if I'm making some mistakes here. Any suggestions?

--

UPDATE: Schematic added below that represents the current (flawed) design.

[image: How it's wired now]

So, I'm hearing two possible solutions to reduce the voltage flowing across the segments when "off" - the first would simply reduce my 18V to 12V. **Others have suggested putting two darlington arrays (e.g., ULN2803) in, which I assume would sit in-between each 74HC595 and the resistors that lead to the individual segment cathodes. Is that right - would it look like this?**

(I'm just showing one assembly of a shift register, darlington array, resistors, and 7-segment display. Also, ignore the stray resistor at the top right.)

[image: Is this right?]

Comment: Schematic please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one handy, but I'll post one later. It's pretty straight-forward, though.

Comment: They usually are straight-forward - if they're done right - which they often aren't ...

Comment: I think this page is showing essentially the right idea using the shift register with the transistor array: http://labalec.fr/erwan/?p=1288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LED displays are being lit by current flowing through the p-channel MOSFETs (and possibly protection diodes) in the HC595s. They can only provide 0V and 5V at the outputs so when they are high (off) you have 18V - 5V = 13V across the LED display + resistor.

You need to lower the 18V to something a bit less. I suggest an LM317 so that you can fiddle with the voltage setting, up to 16.5V or so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq9DkH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response. I admit I don't follow it 100%, but I'll do my homework to try to understand it better.

Comment: FYI, I tried a 15V supply, and still see the problem I described. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, why does it only happen on one of the displays? Shouldn't it happen on both?

Comment: Are the displays identical? Or different colors?

Comment: P.S. check the actual exact supply voltages at both the 74HC595 power pins.

Comment: P.P.S. Also, disconnect all the Arduino data/clock (presumably you are using three lines for data and clocks) lines to rule out any firmware issue.

Comment: The displays are identical. I've tried switching them and I always get the same result for the one hooked to the first 74HC595. BTW, just to clarify, in my circuit, the resistors are between the shift register pins and the 7-segment cathodes. Your diagram shows a single resistor between the supply and the common anode. (Sorry, I know I didn't post a schematic.)

Comment: @josemonkey Yes, it's the same concept with the resistors on the other side (where they have to be, of course). Changed the schematic- better for future reference.

Comment: Rather than reducing the voltage, it would probably be simpler to just add a MOSFET to each output of the '595 to make the outputs open-drain.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yes, that's the preferred solution (although perhaps not simpler). A [ULN2803](http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?pid=ULN2803APG&lang=en&type=datasheet) per HC595 will accomplish it all with an additional two chips total and can handle up to a 50V supply.

Comment: The reason I suggest checking the supply voltages is that an open on the HC595 Vcc supply that appears to be *working* would have the symptoms you describe.

Comment: I agree - adding ULN2803 chips sounds smart, but it would complicate my (admittedly short-sighted) design... which is already soldered. :-(  I suspect lowering my voltage is the easiest thing now, even though I don't seem to be able to make it work nicely with anything higher than 12V. I was hoping to drive this off of alkaline batteries... so I picked two 9V as the easiest option. If I want 12V, I'll need 8 AAs or something... ugh.

Comment: @josemonkey ULN2803 or even discrete transistors is only admissible solution for this problem. Controlling anything supplied from 12V or more directly from HC595 is VERY bad idea.

Comment: @lustful-rat Thanks for your input. Could you explain why it's a bad idea? I'm not saying you're wrong, I just really don't know why it's bad.

Comment: @josemonkey 1. As You noticed LEDs dim in off state - Spehro Pefhany shows You schematic and point directly to the problem, 2. If something goes wrong in LED chain 12V quickly kills Your HC and other logic, 3. Logic gates with CMOS outputs are not designed to control directly loads , 4. It's a good engineering practice to use open drain or open collector outputs to control such loads, it's safe and reliable.

Comment: I got two ULN2003 arrays & I wired as shown in the diagram above. I observed two things:

1. I must have really had something wrong before, because it seems as if the logic to turn segments on / off is reversed. Before, I'd send a byte to the SR with bits set to 0 for the segments that I wanted ON and set to 1 for the ones I wanted off. (That seemed backwards to me, but it yielded the expected output, so I figured I was confused.) Now, it's the opposite - send 1s for on, 0s for off.

Comment: Second, I still get the same result... i.e., if I apply 18V to the common anode, segments remain dimly lit when they ought to be off.

Any suggestions, @SpehroPefhany or @lustful-rat?

Comment: Did you disconnect the data and clocks as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I just tried without the arduino at all. Applying 5V to the inputs on the ULN2003 lights up those segments. But when they are attached to ground, they remain dimly lit.

Comment: So, I guess my problem is still the 18V current. Seems like the solution is to stick with 12V, and use the transistor arrays to protect the registers from the higher voltage.

Comment: Something else entirely is wrong. Are you sure you don't have something else connected to those LED leads?

Comment: I appreciate your continued responses... Yes, I disconnected everything from the display... Arduino not even connected. Just one transistor array, resistors, and one display. If I put 18V on the common anode from the display and 5V on the transistor array input pins, the proper segments light up. If I remove the 5V, the segments stay dimly lit.

Comment: Maybe PCB fault or some other sneak path resistive or to +5 - bet it does that even without the uln2003.

Comment: [This is what I have now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iHRvu.jpg) (Sorry, can't figure out how to insert image.)

Comment: Everything just on a breadboard at the moment.

Comment: Am I just being really dumb? Is applying 18V the problem, period? The segment display says the forward voltage is 12.4V max. I assumed that if I limited the current with a resistor that I'd be ok with a higher voltage. Is that a fundamental flaw, or am I getting that right?

Comment: No, your concept is fine. Ah, I see your problem! COM must go to +18/+12 or just leave it open. Connecting it to +5 is what is causing your current problem!

Comment: Ah! You are correct. Removing +5V from the COM pin makes the dim lighting go away! Thank you very much. Just out of curiosity... would there be a significant difference if I put +18V on that pin rather than leave it open?

Comment: No, it's there for inductive loads like relays.